# Why are nested interfaces declared implicitly static?

Tags: java, interface

as the title says, why nested interfaces are implicitly static.Why cant i use nested interfaces just like nested classes ie like with static and without static

Comment: Refer http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-static-nested-or-inner-interfaces.php

Comment: @Zeeker, not so. OP is asking about interface definitions themselves, not their members.

Comment: @robert He is asking about nested interface, speaks interfaces in interfaces. In that case the nested interface is just a member of another interface. At least if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Zeeker, that would be an *instance* of an interface (or strictly speaking an instance of an object that implements the interface). He's asking about interface declaration.

Comment: @robert I think you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/08/inner-interface-in-java/

Comment: Because [JLS §8.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1). Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

From the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class
>   and has direct access to that object's methods and fields

i.e. it maintains a reference to its enclosing instance.

An interface on the other and is just a static definition of type. A contract, used to provide some polymorphism.

An interface cannot itself be instantiated, therefor it cannot have state, and thus it cannot "know" about an enclosing instance.

Answer (score -2):

Java `interface` are interfaces. A interface rule is [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation_failure). The I in ACID means:

```
To demonstrate isolation, we assume two transactions execute 
at the same time, each attempting to modify the same data.
```

So fields are automatically `public static final`.

Comment: This answer is complete and utter nonsense. Interfaces and transactions have exactly nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @EJP I never said a interface is a transaction. I said one rule for interfaces is ACID. Not only in database-transactions. You think about database-transactions but there are more kind of transactions.